# Why won't my bootstrap tooltips work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying, but I simply cannot find out why my bootstrap tooltips won't work. This is my entire file http://pastie.org/5399296 And here is the link to the page http://pages.nbscraft.net/bootstrap/DonatePage.html But I just cannot get the tooltips to work.

Comment: Make sure to look at the console for javascript errors before posting a question. You're calling $ before you include jQuery. You will see a javascript error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$` before you include jQuery.

Move the following section

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tip').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

to the end of the page:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tip').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

btw, it's always a good practice to put all JS at the end of a page.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have just asked before wasting over an hour.

Comment: @user1834678 btw, you can accept this as the answer by clicking the check mark on the left :-)

Comment: Yep, I was waiting for the 10 minute timer thing to go down though. btw thanks again!